# Is memory usage better with One Big Process or many small Processes?

Tags: python, unix, memory, subprocess

I have a memory hungry application that iterates through a pair of arrays, processing every combination of elements. Currently this script is very RAM-hungry. It ends up using around 3GB of RAM.

My question is this:

Is it more memory efficient to process each combination of elements in one large process? Or is it better to start a new subprocess for each combination.

In other words, is it better to do option 1:

```
for i in param_set1:
    for j in paramset2:
        Do_A_Big_Job(i, j)
```

Or option 2:

```
import subprocess

for i in param_set1:
    for j in paramset2:
        subprocess.call([Do_A_Big_Job_Script, i, j])
```

By "better", I mean "use less RAM".

Thanks!

**Edit**
I'm explicitly curious about memory usage. When the process ends, would a UNIX system free up that memory? Is this more efficient than python's garbage collection for a *reasonably* well written script? I don't have a lot of cores available, so I would expect the multiple processes to run more or less in parallel anyway.

Comment: The memory usage depends enterily on what you are doing on your "jobs" (what variables you are assigning and freeing), not on how you distribute them. If each job uses a lot of memory, running them in parallel would make the memory stack. The only adventage is that it *may* be faster.

Comment: I would post it as an answer, but I don't think it really qualifies as an answer xD I was just trying to point out that you may have been questioning the wrong thing. Your edit seems to be a more precise question and it's worth waiting for someone that knows about that topic. Btw, it would help adding some tags, to make the question easy to find (like UNIX, memory, subprocess, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Running a single process will use less RAM of course, but it makes it difficult to take advantage of multiple cpus/cores.

If you don't care how long it takes, run a single process.

As a compromise, you could run just a few processes at a time instead of launching them all at once.